# ios get a element from nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need to find string which start with "©" in `<caption>` tag and ends before `</caption>` tag.

For example in this string it will be:

```
Le pop-up "AENAON hellas made", mode produite en Grèce donc, propose une multi <caption><p></p><img class="size-full wp-image-36678" src="https://vivreaberlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dimitrios-ourdoulidis.jpg" alt="" width="960" height="700" /> © Dimitrios Ourdoulidis</caption><br />

Et c'est très agréable de voir une boutique éphémère qui ouvre la voie à de nouveaux designers encore inconnus à Berlin. <br></br><h2>De la mode pointue</h2> <caption><p></p><img class="wp-image-36607 size-full" src="https://vivreaberlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/big-athens.png" alt="" width="1000" height="670" /> © Dig Athens</caption><br />
```

© Dimitrios Ourdoulidis

© Dig Athens

Comment: Unfortunately It does work only with 1 element with "©"

Comment: in your question you say "I need to find string which start with "©"" as advice in your next questions in StackOverflow please make your requirements clear to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into regular expressions for this kind of string matching.

I don't really work with objective c but here's what I did on Swift to get it to work.

```
var regex = ">([^>])*(</caption>)"
var testString = "Le pop-up \"AENAON hellas made\", mode produite en donc, propose une multi <caption><p></p><img class=\"size-full wp-image-36678\" src=\"https://vivreaberlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dimitrios-ourdoulidis.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"960\" height=\"700\" /> © Dimitrios Ourdoulidis</caption><br />\r\n\r\nEt c'est  de voir une boutique qui ouvre la voie de nouveaux designers encore inconnus  Berlin. <br></br><h2>De la mode pointue</h2> <caption><p></p><img class=\"wp-image-36607 size-full\" src=\"https://vivreaberlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/big-athens.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"1000\" height=\"670\" /> © Dig Athens</caption><br />"

let regularExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: .caseInsensitive)
let matches = regularExpression.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, (testString as NSString).length))
print(testString)

matches.forEach {
    let range = $0.range
    let strictRange = NSMakeRange(range.lowerBound + 2, range.length - 12)

    print((testString as NSString).substring(with: strictRange) as String)
}
```

The regular expression `/>([^>])*(</caption>)/` matches the ending `>` and `</caption>`

so for your example string one of the matches would be `> © Dimitrios Ourdoulidis</caption>`

To overcome that, I've reduced the range of the matches by 2 from the front of the string, and by 10 from the behind.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular this `@"©{1,1}(.)*(</){1,1}"` expression, you can get those substrings, and after that replacing the `"</"` by `""` will return what you expect

```
- (NSMutableArray*)substrings:(NSString*)candidateString{

    NSRegularExpression * exp = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:@"©{1,1}(.)*(</){1,1}" options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [exp enumerateMatchesInString:candidateString options:NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds range:NSMakeRange(0, candidateString.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [resultArray addObject:[[candidateString substringWithRange:[result range]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</" withString:@""]];
    }];

    NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
    return resultArray;
}
```

> Input:

```
NSString* str2 = @"Le pop-up \"AENAON hellas made\", mode produite en Grèce donc, propose une multi <caption><p></p><img class=\"size-full wp-image-36678\" src=\"https://vivreaberlin.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/dimitrios-ourdoulidis.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"960\" height=\"700\" /> © Dimitrios Ourdoulidis</caption><br />";
```

> Output
>
> 2018-01-26 15:43:30.486182+0100 RegexTestingProject[58921:2174408] (
>       "\U00a9 Dimitrios Ourdoulidis" )